# Elm: Is there any url router that works for version 0.17?

Tags: elm

Is there any elm router that works for version 0.17?

There are several of them that are not compatible with the latest release.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Any router heavily relies on `elm-community/elm-history` package, which is [not upgraded to 0.17](https://github.com/elm-community/elm-history/issues/17) yet.

Comment: It seems that this one: http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/Bogdanp/elm-route/2.0.2/ works for 0.17. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently a router is not needed any more, according to https://github.com/etaque/elm-routing-example

> Do we need routers?
>
> I don't think so anymore, at least since Elm 0.17 and port modules, and I say that as the author of elm-transit-router, one of the three main routers for Elm 0.16.
>
> We need packages for route parsing: that is, a way to transform the string representation of the path or hash to our app internal model. There are a few packages for this already: Bogdanp/elm-route and etaque/elm-route-parser (disclaimer: I'm the author). sporto/hop also has parsing tools but it isn't yet migrated to 0.17.
>
> For the rest, Elm is already efficient at the job, it's just a few Msg away!
>
> In this example I added a fancy transition effect to illustrate my point: if you implement routing by yourself, you gain more power for specific behaviours.
>
> Note: browser history handling is done with ports for now, but it will be >easy to upgrade when the Elm bindings will be ready.